# Incorrect coordinates in persp3D plot with bathy class object

Tags: r, rgl

I'm trying to plot an object of the bathy class using a persp3D but, although the surface it is correct in the plot, the axis coordinates are wrong.

```
library(OceanView)
library(marmap)

bathy<- getNOAA.bathy(lon1 = -90, lon2 = -60, lat1 = 20, lat2 = 29, resolution = 2, keep = T)

persp3D(z=bathy, col= jet.col (n = 100, alpha = 1), colkey=T, scale = F, 
        expand=0.05, plot = FALSE, xlab="longitude", 
          ylab="latitude", zlab="depth")

plotrgl(lighting = TRUE, smooth = TRUE)
```

[image: figure example]

How can I fix this? I tried to convert the bathymetric data to other object class, such as xyz or RasterLayer, in order to define the x and y parameters but then I was unable to plot it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is the way `persp3d` understands `bathy` when only `z` is passed. See `x`, `y`, `z` arguments in `?persp3d`. If you also pass `x` and `y`, then the axes are fine. With the minimal `persp3d` example we have:

```
persp3d(x=seq(-90, -60, length=nrow(bathy)),
        y=seq(20, 29, length=ncol(bathy)),
        z=bathy)
```

Comment: Thank you Vincent!

Comment: Wasn't the question about `persp3D`, rather than `persp3d`?

Comment: you're right! just realized that. apparently the OP is happy with the answer maybe because persp3D and perps3d seems quite similar.

Comment: Correct, the solution presented work with both functions. In fact, the persp3D() is an extended version of the persp function, according the author of the plot3D and the OceanView packages.